# RadGrid client binding get_masterTableView() is null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am setting the datasource at the client side but the get_masterTableView returns null

```
var tableView = radGrid
     .get_masterTableView();
```

i tried it setting on button click just to be sure that the Radgrid is completely created but it still returns null.. This is my code

```
<h4>Client Side Binding</h4>

<telerik:RadButton 
    ID="RadButton1" 
    AutoPostBack="False"
    OnClientClicked="RadButton1_OnClientClicked"
    runat="server" 
    Text="Load Items"></telerik:RadButton>

<telerik:RadGrid 
    ID="RadGrid1" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    runat="server">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn
                DataField="Name"
                HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn
                DataField="Age"
                HeaderText="Age">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn
                DataField="Address.City"
                HeaderText="City">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings>
        <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="RadGrid1_OnGridCreated" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and this is on the **Javascript**

```
<telerik:RadScriptBlock runat="server">
    <script>
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            //rebindGrid();
        }

        function RadButton1_OnClientClicked(sender, args) {
            rebindGrid();
        }

        function RadGrid1_OnGridCreated(sender, args) {
            //rebindGrid();
        }

        function rebindGrid() {
            var ds = dataSource();
            var radGrid = $find('<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>');
            var tableView = radGrid
               .get_masterTableView();

            console.log(radGrid);

            if (tableView) {
                tableView.set_dataSource(ds);
                tableView.dataBind();
                tableView.set_virtualItemCount(2);
            } else {
                alert('Table View is null');
            }
        }

        function dataSource() {
            var items = [];

            items.push({
                Name: 'Enteng',
                Age: 25,
                Address: {
                    City: 'Dipolog City'
                }
            });

            items.push({
                Name: 'Vincent',
                Age: 27,
                Address: {
                    City: 'Dumaguete City'
                }
            });

            return items;
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadScriptBlock>
```

**pageLoad** doesn't work

**RadButton1_OnClientClicked** doesn't work

**RadGrid1_OnGridCreated** doesn't work

any help would be appreciated..

TYI

Answer (score 2):

OnGridCreated should work. I think there is a bug in your code:

This:

```
var radGrid = $find('<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>');
```

should look like:

```
var radGrid = $find('#<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>');
```

Alternatively you can use the sender argument to get a handle on your radgrid:

```
function RadGrid1_OnGridCreated(sender, args) {
   rebindGrid(sender);
}

function rebindGrid(sender) {
   var tableView = sender.get_masterTableView();
   ... etc
```

**EDIT:**

As stated in the comment below the problem is that **the radgird is not bound to any data
source. Thus get_masterTableView() returns null.**

The following piece of code, that binds the grid to a dummy data source, solves the problem:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RadGrid1.DataSource = new List<int>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. $find('#<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>'); <- # is not necessary in telerik.. when you look at radGrid via console.log, it returns a RadGrid object generated

Comment: hm ... you are right. The only possible cause I can think of is that you need to init the data source of your rad grid ... In order to make the grid load its MasterTableView object you have to set some empty data source in the initial load.